# vertically align text in HTML list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On [this page](http://festivals.ie:8080/aviation/) there's a menu in the right sidebar that is composed of a HTML list with this structure:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="index.html"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="development.html">Development</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="management.html">Management</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="learning.html">Learning</a>
    </li>

    <!-- more menu entries -->
</ul>
```

Notice that some menu entries have (font) icons to the left of the label, whereas others don't. This makes the menu appear rather unsightly, because the labels are not vertically aligned.

Is there are any way to vertically align the labels, ideally without introducing additional HTML elements (because that messes up some immediate descendant rules that are defined within Bootstrap itself)?

Comment: reference link is not working..

Comment: If your icons are a standard size, such as 16px, then you could use offset the `left` of the `li` or inner `a` with something along the lines of `left:-16px;` + any extra pixels for fine tuning. MAy also need to play with `position:relative` on your `ul` and positions of `li`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.nav-pills.nav-stacked > li > a {
  padding-left: 25px;
}


.nav-pills.nav-stacked > li > a > i {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```

It takes the icons out of the flow, puts the text 25px to the right,  and then positions the icons 25px to the left